# Firewall from iptables with NAT

Tags: iptables

Learning iptables for study so nothing too critical. An iptables firewall must sit between a DHCP router (internet) and a local LAN with client PC's. The firewall will allow the client internet, but it will block ftp and some other ports etc.

- `eth0` is to internet
- `eth1` is to LAN (so of course two networks)

I am working to understand the commands better. First I have used the following three lines to enable `iptables` to forward packets between both networks. This below seems to work and client PC can browse internet now. Not sure if it was most elegant way.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

From here I am unsure. Not many examples seem to use the masquerade/NAT.

I was under the impression I am best to drop all packets then allow what is needed specifically. The order apparently matters.

Can I now drop all packets and then allow port 80? How do I now approach to block and allow?

Does the masquerade affect how I do this? It looks to me all packets are now forwarded straight to other card so how do I tell only port 80 is allowed?

I am also unsure about inbound/outbound (from client perspective)in relation to what ports. Allow all outbound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things of note here – the first is that, in practice, NAT provides a firewall which prevents any incoming traffic EXCEPT where it is associated with outbound traffic. That's what you have configured above. The first line turns on address translation, the second allows incoming packets associated with outgoing ones through and the third line allows all outgoing packets through. OUTBOUND here means traffic from your LAN to the INTERNET, INBOUND means from the INTERNET to your LAN.

If you only wanted to allow browsing the web, there are a few ways to do it.  The first would be to only allow outbound requests for port 80 (and accept the associated incoming requests). You could do that as follows:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE    
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp -dport 80 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

The first 2 rules are the same, the third one is only allowing port 80 requests to leave the network, and the fourth may or may not be required depending on your defaults – it says to drop all other forwarded traffic.

This poses some potential issues. In order to browse a web site, you need to do a DNS lookup to convert the domain name into an IP address. If your router is providing DNS, then you are OK (the rules above only deal with traffic being forwarded through the router, not traffic originating from or terminating on the router). If you are using external DNS servers, you will need to allow DNS through as well. DNS speaks on TCP and UDP port 53, so you would need to add:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p ucp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

When it comes to using IPTABLES, you are quite right that order matters. Rules are handled in the order they are in the table, so if you have an `ACCEPT` rule before a `DROP` rule where both rules match the traffic will go through. You can INSERT rules at the beginning of a table by using `iptables -I` or you can APPEND rules to the end of the table using `iptables -A`.

There are also multiple paths, not all packets go through all paths. This can get complex, but in the simple case above you have 3 paths to worry about: `INPUT`, `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD`. `INPUT` are requests destined for the router.  `OUTPUT` are requests originating on the router. `FORWARD` are requests going into and out of the router.

Comment: Note: in the `iptables` documentation these "paths" are called "chains".